# FindPeaks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a simple diffraction pattern with several peaks that I'm attempting to characterize.

I've been using the [`findpeaks` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) but I find it changes the independent domain's index.  Is there a way to apply this function to data and have the output in terms of my independent variable?

```
pre_norm=p_pre./max(p_pre).*100
findpeaks(pre_norm,'MinPeakProminence',1,'WidthReference','halfheight')
[pks,loc,w]=findpeaks(pre_norm,'MinPeakProminence',1,'WidthReference','halfheight')
```

Comment: What is your independent variable here? `findpeaks` will return an *index* which you can then use to index into your independent variable.

Comment: The independent variable, in this case, is the d-spacing.  Can I use the independent variable in the findpeaks function so the output is automatically in terms of the independent variable?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`findpeaks` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html?refresh=true#bufhyo1-1), you can specify the locations of your samples using the second input parameter. Now, instead of the index being returned as the location of the peak, the location value corresponding to the peak will be returned.

```
[peaks, locs] = findpeaks(pre_norm, d_spacing);
```